# EJB3 & Websphere Application Server 7: NoClassDefFoundError on Remote EJB

Tags: websphere, ejb-3.0

I have been trying all day to connect to a Remote EJB on a Websphere Application Server 7. This configuration is necessary for project specific reasons. Its goal is to connect two applications together that are on independent EAR but on the same server.

I have been trying to access a dummy method that does not have any parameters.
The lookup URL is the one copied from the EJB deployment on my local server and it complies with EJB3.0 IBM specifications according to the information [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html#cejbbindingsejbfp__ejb30defaultbindings). 
I have seen several other posts on stackoverflow related to EJB Remote issues in WAS (but I cannot link all threads because of my user limitations) but they do not resolve or are not the same as my problem. 
Local EJB invocation works fine.

Here is the implementation. I do not use any specific IBM WAS libraries in the imports:

The class that is connecting to the Remote EJB:

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2809");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
Object object = ctx.lookup("ejb/<component-id>#<package.qualified.interface>");
RemoteInterface interface = (RemoteInterface)javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(object, RemoteInterface.class);
String sResponse = (String)interface.dummy();
```

The definition of the remote interface is:

```
@Remote
public interface RemoteInterface {
    public String dummy() throws Exception;
}
```

And my implementation is:

```
@Override
public String dummy() throws Exception {
    return "string";
}
```

Environment information:

- Websphere Application Server 7
- JDK 1.6
- EJB 3.0
- EAR 5.0

Maybe someone can give me some pointers on what to do next.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have replaced <component-id> and <package.qualified.interface> with the actual values.... but have you looked in your SystemOut.log for the CNTR0167I message corresponding to your bean?  As each bean is bound into JNDI, the CNTR0167I messages are logged to make it easy to determine the exact lookup string to use.

Also, setting INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY and PROVIDER_URL should not be needed if running in the same server process.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Yes, I used the CNTR0167I to find out exactly what the interface jndi is and used those values that comply with IBM specifications. I also tried without the Properties settings, but with no success. Having IBM support, they are supposed to be looking into it and in the meantime I am connecting to the logic in the remote EJB via REST.